# PHP not running under same user as Apache

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, debian

I installed Wordpress on a local machine. However, to install plugins, it's always asking me for FTP credentials. There's [a post about why this is happening](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/why-wordpress-asks-connection-info/). So, here's what I did:

I went to the file `wp-admin/includes/file.php`, and commented the `unlink` line, so that the temporary file does not get deleted. Then I went to check the permissions on that file, which were `-rw-r--r-- www-data www-data`. This is good, because I want the Apache server to run as `www-data:www-data`.

Also, however, I `var_dump`'ed `getmyuid()` and  `@fileowner($temp_file_name)`. The result I got was `1000` (`xedinunknown`) and `33` (`www-data`). This means that while Apache is running as `www-data`, PHP is running as `xedinunknown` (correct me if I'm wrong please). The question is: **why is that**?

I have suEXEC installed, but disabled, and it looks like I'm running PHP as an Apache module (`etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load` has this entry: `LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`).

Just to recap, I'm running PHP 5.5.4 / Apache 2.4.6 on Debian 7.1 64-bit.

Right now, I changed `envvars` for Apache to run as xedinunknown:www-data, `chown`'ed the lock directory, and restarted. This allows me to install plugins, but I would like to think that this is just a temporary measure

**UPDATE**

Ok, fair enough. Here's output of `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`:

```
core_module (static)
log_config_module (static)
logio_module (static)
version_module (static)
mpm_prefork_module (static)
http_module (static)
so_module (static)
alias_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authz_default_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
cgi_module (shared)
dav_module (shared)
dav_fs_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
fcgid_module (shared)
include_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
php5_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
```

Comment: Looks like you run php as fast cgi

Comment: Added enabled modules. Is there a way to know for certain which handler is being user? Also, is there a way to configure permissions properly so that everything works with CGI/FCGI? And what determines the user under which PHP runs eventually?

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, I used the following, and it worked:

```
sudo chown -R _www:_www {path to wordpress folder}
```

_www is the user that PHP runs under on the Mac. *(You can change this to whatever your PHP install runs under on your specific OS)*

*(You may also need to chmod some folders too. I had done that first and it didn't fix it. It wasn't until I did the chown command that it worked, so I'm not sure if it was the chown command alone, or a combination of chmod and chown.)*